Has the US said why electing judges is bad in Mexico but good in the US?
The US ambassador to Mexico has criticised the proposed changes to the appointment of judges:

Based on my lifelong experience supporting the rule of law, I believe popular direct election of judges is a major risk to the functioning of Mexico’s democracy.

My understanding is that many judges are directly elected in the US.  It therefore seems odd that US officials would have such a negative view of this change.  Have there been any official explanations of why this is so risky for Mexico but not for the US?

Its possible that there is no contradiction: the ambassador may believe the same about directly elected judges in the US.

@PaulJohnson I do not know how these things work, but should not public statements of this form represent the opinion of the US government rather than the individual opinion of the ambassador?

There are no elected federal judges in the US.

"@PaulJohnson ... but should not public statements of this form represent the opinion of the US government rather than the individual opinion of the ambassador?" I suppose when specifically directed by the President. Or if that is a general plank for that specific diplomatic position. Otherwise, the ambassador is probably free to express his own opinions and expect them to have some weight (depending on the nation they represent ofcourse). In this case, there would probably be more than a few fellow Americans, and even a fair number of Mexicans, who agree with him entirely.

@Jen But, the U.S. has more elected state court judges than any other country in the world and few states have no judicial elections. https://www.ojp.gov/ncjrs/virtual-library/abstracts/judicial-selection-united-states-special-report

@user30575 I am in Southern California and I have seen county judges on my ballot. I never voted for them because I felt under-qualified to vote for a judge. I am not 100% sure if it was to elect a judge but I'm pretty sure because it was to choose a judge among a few judges.

@CaveJohnson Thanks for the info. "Superior court judges ... are elected by county voters ... at a general election .... Vacancies occurring during those terms ... are filled through appointment by the Governor." --newsroom.courts.ca.gov does confirm that at least one US state elects judges directly.

@ouflak an ambassador's job is to represent a country's government to a foreign country and to promote the represented country's foreign policy.  If an ambassador wants to express personal opinion in public, she or he must be very clear about the personal nature of the statement and disclaim any connection between the statement and the government's policy.

It is not clear that the premise of the question is strictly correct. The ambassador, and indeed the Biden administration, may well be opposed to the election of judges in the United States as well. This would not be particularly surprising; over half the states in the USA do not elect judges to their state supreme courts, and there is no particular reason to expect a given administration to approve of one strategy versus another, though the most populous Republican state (Texas) has partisan elections and the most populous Democratic state (California) has appointments.
One can point to many other examples where presidential administrations have opposed common state laws; for instance, abortion is banned or partially banned in many parts of the USA, but the current administration largely opposes this policy. Because the president does not have unlimited power to set state policy—nor indeed national policy, if the legislature or the constitution impede them from doing so—it is perfectly possible for there to be laws in the United States that a given administration opposes—even without considering the possibility that the ambassador might have expressed a personal opinion that differs from that of the current US government.
That said, the Mexican government's proposal is quite different from both the current Mexican system and the USA system. Most notably, it would allow for direct election of national supreme court justices, which is not the case in the USA, nor currently in Mexico. In fact, it seems to apply mostly or solely to federal judicial positions; again, in the USA, all such positions are appointed by the executive branch and confirmed by the legislature, which is similar to the process currently used in Mexico.
Looking at the American embassy's statement, linked in the question, we see that the ambassador also writes that:

[...]the proposal as it stands removes the necessary requirements of
having the highest qualifications for judges, including in the
reduction of the required years of experience to serve at all levels
of the judiciary.

So they also seem to be worried about the specifics of relatively unrestricted election of judges, which may not be the case in all the US states that have elected judges (though many requirements will still be retained in the Mexican government's proposal).
Furthermore,  however, if the ambassador does in fact believe that the risk is greater in Mexico, one possible explanation may also be found in the embassy's statement:

Direct elections would also make it easier for cartels and other bad
actors to take advantage of politically motivated and inexperienced
judges.

The ambassador may believe that the risk of manipulation by cartels is higher in Mexico than elsewhere (regardless of the merits of this argument).

Somewhat useful backgrounder. A quote from there "The rest of the world is stunned and amazed at what we do, and vaguely aghast. They think that the idea that judges with absolutely no no-judge-specific education training are running political campaigns is both insane and characteristically American." If the State Department is willing to host such opinions...

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I don't see that quote in the transcript of your link, had you meant to link a different page?

@DanGetz: it's not in the transcript but it is in the slides that get shown on screen, at the 13 minutes mark. He's not merely reading the slides though.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Key quote from the link: "90 percent of state judges altogether run for – have to face election to keep their jobs." Also, the U.S. is very exceptional in having a significant number of non-lawyer, not legally trained, trial court judges. 32 states have them. "many litigants in these states “experience a courtroom in which often no one, not even the judge, is aware of the law [or that] the one person in the courtroom who is aware of the law is the attorney for the more powerful party[.]"” https://courtslaw.jotwell.com/non-lawyer-judges-in-devalued-courts/

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever: FWIW, the implication that "running political campaigns" is a relevant end in itself, rather than a part of the process, and the idea that a specialized expert (someone with only judge-specific education) would be somehow unsuitable for that, strikes me as much more "characteristically American".

Well, the US State Department was willing to host a seminar [ostensibly to inform the foreign press] about the US judges elections [at state level] in which the main speaker put up a slide (around minute 25) with the conclusion that

A significant body of empirical scholarship finds a relations between campaign donations and judicial decisions in favor of donors' preferences.

So, a US ambassador translating that in Mexico's context with some suggestion that organized crime will thus be capable to buy judges that way (see Obie's last quote) isn't so outlandish in that perspective.
(The presentation is overall a bit more balanced than that, towards the end -- min 42 -- it does discuss/summarize both pros and cons.)
Criminal organizations in Mexico seem to [try to] control elections mostly through assassinations, at least on the level that data is easy to gather, i.e. body counts. But surely there have been allegations (from DEA informants) that even some Mexican presidents had campaign funding from the drug cartels, at least at some point in their careers, and that their policies thereafter reflected that.

Something that both prevents the U.S. law enforcement and judicial system from being entirely captured by organized crime, but also prevents it from being entirely free of corruption everywhere, is that it is highly decentralized. No other county has such a large share of law enforcement run by independently elected local governments and so little national and top level subnational (i.e. state) governments. Only 12% of incarcerations are from, and only 2% of criminal trials are in, federal courts. Just 0.3% of non-bankruptcy civil cases are in federal court. Most state DAs are elected locally.

83% of the 1.214 million U.S. law enforcement officers are employed at the city and county level. https://bjs.ojp.gov/library/publications/census-state-and-local-law-enforcement-agencies-2018-statistical-tables About two-thirds are the rest are federal, and about one-third of the rest of state and tribal law enforcement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_enforcement_in_the_United_States Even then, they are broken up between scores of independent federal law enforcement agencies and multiple law enforcement agencies at the state level in every state.

@ohwilleke What do you mean by "also prevents it from being entirely free of corruption everywhere"?  Is that a condition that's ever existed in any nation of non-trivial size?  I would argue that fundamental human nature prevents this, and so some lesser factor is largely irrelevant.

@MasonWheeler What I mean is, that if you have a small number of law enforcement agencies, it is feasible to have a lowest common denominator level of corruption be very low, if those few agencies set high standards. When you have 18,000 law enforcement agencies, it is more or less inevitable that some of them will be very corrupt and there is really no way to stamp that out.

Looking at this statement:

I believe popular direct election of judges is a major risk to the functioning of Mexico’s democracy.

The ambassador applies it for Mexico, specifically, rather than democracy, generally. This is conjecture, but one reason this may be a problem for Mexico, specifically, is because of the drug cartels. One recent study found them to be the country's fifth largest employer. A 2014 study (via Wikipedia) claimed 3.2 million people in Mexico depended on the cartels for their livelihoods, and the first study showed numbers are significantly up since that time, rather than down.
Bribery and corruption is already enough of a problem in Mexico. The cartels have sufficient numbers to directly influence elections... especially local elections, both with electors and campaign money and even directly buying votes. If they gain the ability to elect their chosen judges in the districts where they operate most, it could be even worse.
This also directly speaks to the "functioning of Mexico's Democracy", rather than just causing problems from corruption, generally, when one considers judges can become involved in deciding electoral disputes.

Hi. Your second paragraph makes it look like the main issue with cartels is they have a lot of electors. I think another important problem is they have a lot of money, so they can finance a candidate's campaign in exchange for future favours.

@Stef Good point. updated.

The generic concerns with electing a judge versus appointing a judge typically revolve around impartial application of the law.
If a judge is elected to a set term, with multiple terms possible, they end up applying the law in a way that gets them reelected, not necessarily impartially.
If the election is for a life term (or until stepping down), you have pressure from whatever body gets you to the point where you can be elected (in the USA, that would be a political party, which is a non-elected, non-public entity) and there is generally a mechanism to remove an elected official who got elected by lying or otherwise misrepresenting their views (To keep with the US example, that would be impeachment).
Appointing judges, theoretically, separates them from the political process (though you can see particularly in SCOTUS that doesn't always happen as expected, mostly due to the aforementioned political parties).
On top of all of the above concerns, you have to factor in the particulars of culture, political structure, and another important factor that you can view as stability or political longevity. In cultures prone to protesting (France as an example) electing a judge may be a more stable path forward than appointing one, as the culture leans more toward the democratic will of the people. In a Direct Democracy (Versus the US Representative Democracy) the legal system may be flatter, which may point to a greater importance of appointing judges impartially, rather than electing them. Political longevity is what I refer to (tongue in cheek) as the propensity for a political figure to fall out of a window. Simply put, anything that can sway the judgement of a judicial figure could potentially threaten or upend the existing political clime, and judges (who typically have the final say in a democracy) are particularly and disproportionately prone to being affected if the process doesn't at least try to prevent such issues.
Do note that I'm not advocating for any particular approach to creating or filling a judicial position, as I have yet to see a mechanism that works fully as intended.
